# Unable to boot Win 7 Guest OS on VMWare Fusion

Tags: vmware, vmware-fusion

Why so many "Virtual Disk" .vmdk files got created under ""Documents/Virtual Machines.Localized/Windows7 x64.vmwarevm/", now Im left with no space, unable to boot guest windows7 OS

Please [click here](https://drive.google.com/a/dotweb.in/file/d/0Bxed_8T6OPe4SnAyb1RWNU9iclk/view?usp=drivesdk) to view the screenshot.

Comment: I think this is quite off topic for SO

Answer (score 0):

Under the VM settings, open the hard disk then expand advanced options, you are probably splitting the vmdk into multiple files. You can also choose to pre-allocate the space or not.

You can move the vm folder to another drive and register once more in fusion, should you have space on another drive.

I always keep my vdisks as one file and don't pre-allocate the space (thin provisioning).